# How do I get my flexbox to align divs to the left when it wraps to a new row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So i have a list of 30 something objects i will be loading in with ajax, as soon as i get my formatting correct i will take care of that, however i cant seem to get my flex-box css to adjust my flex items to the left side when it wraps to a new row...

http://i40.photobucket.com/albums/e240/ocfighter/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-18%20at%2012.34.51%20AM%20copy.jpg

i would like for the three bottom divs to be on the left side instead of dispersed through out the middle of the second row....

my container div for all of the divs you see displayed

```
#movies {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.center {
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

html

```
<div id="movies" class="center">
  <div class="movies_cell center">
  <div class="movies_image">
      <a href=""><img src="img/movies/fatheroflights.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="movies_detail">
   <a href=""><h1>Father of Lights</h1></a>
   <img src="img/rating/5.png" alt="" style="margin: auto;">
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post the html document.

Comment: Change `justify-content: center;` to `justify-content: flex-start;`

Comment: just tried it adding to the class .center, unsuccessful

Comment: for some reason it worked when i added a margin into the container div..... doesnt make any sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
   justify-content: flex-start;
```

Unless for some reason you want the first row to be in the center unless it's too big for the container, that would be more complicated.